# how to make a grid view using table view in ipad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, gridview, tableview

hello i want to make a grid view using a table view and display data from the array.
i m new for iPhone Application .
please  send me the the answer how to make a grid view in iPhone and I pad ?
please suggest how to make it easy ?

Comment: This question is way too broad to be covered here. If you are new to iPhone development, then you need to start with the basics and work your way up to developing custom views. Start with Apple's development guides, check out tutorials online, and consider picking up a book on iPhone development. Then, if you encounter problems implementing your grid view, post specific questions and code here for us to help you with.

Comment: Have you even searched? There are loads of examples out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView). It is very similar to using the standard UITableView, but displays a grid of cells rather than a single column of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually very simple.....
The bast way to do it is by using UITableView
You can create custom cell and use in your tableView.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show your data in grid view using tableview then just make a table view with UITableViewCell and in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

just put your array value in cell. you can access your array value like

```
-- [arrName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

If further clarification then tell me